# Sending a email from a Bootstrap model + Django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

So i had the form working and sending on a different page but i wanted to put the form into a pop-up. I have been trying to understand why it now is not working and stripped it back to the basics. The submit button does not seem to do anything.

I have been trying to debug it for half an hour now and have a peice of code that should print 'POST' in the cmd if the request method is post. (This is where i validate and send the email, right?. Thats how it worked before)

```
def motors(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print 'GET'
        form = MotorEnquire()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print 'POST'

    print 'Working'
    motors = Motors.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'motors.html', {'motors': motors, 'form': form})
```

The Form in template:

```
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form.as_p }}
                        <div class="form-actions">
                          <button type="submit">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

When i click send nothing happens, im exspecting something to print to the cmd. When i load the page i get both print messages that i should be getting 'GET' and 'Working'

I still have my old code that worked until i moved everything and took away the urls because i put it into the bootstrap model.

Any ideas of why it wouldnt be working or better ways to debug it and see what is broke?

Thank you. If you need anything else please just ask.

Forgot to mention, validation has stopped working when i press send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `method` defined inside your `<form>` but there is no action - how your page would know where to send your data? You need to add `action` attribute with proper URL to your view like

```
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'your_view_url' %}">
```

---

You should also take a look at the [Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/) Django's documentation section - there is even a simple [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-template) of how you should write your form's html

Comment: I did think of this, thank you for your comment :). Can anyone explain why sometimes i would need this but others not?

Comment: where exactly you do not need this?

Comment: This form worked yesterday with the code i had - it had no action :P i though it must default to the page its currently on, guessing not :P